# What is NoSQL, and when would someone use it over a relational database like MySQL?

Tags: nosql

What is the difference between NoSQL and a relational database like MySQL, and what are the advantages of NoSQL?

When should it be used over (for example) MySQL?

Comment: it's like having the benefit of a database without ever having to use SQL, ADO, or any of that stuff - http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Storray_Engine.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

NoSQL is a category of database engines that do not support the SQL (Structured Query Language) in order to achieve performance or reliability features that are incompatible with the flexibility of SQL.

These engines usually provide a query language that provides a subset of what SQL can do, plus some additional features. What subset of SQL is available depends entirely on the engine, though it's fairly common that `JOIN`, `TRANSACTION`, `LIMIT` and non-indexed `WHERE` are not supported.

As a consequence, porting existing software from a standard SQL database engine to a NoSQL engine will require a rewrite of *all* the queries in that software, and will probably also require some changes in the application logic itself (a classic example being that "display page 11 of 25" is impossible to do efficiently in CouchDB, due to lack of `LIMIT x OFFSET y` support).

Wikipedia has a nice [list of NoSQL engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

The general consensus on NoSQL seems to be that if some specific part of your software would benefit from the improved performance, reliability or scalability allowed by a specific NoSQL engine, and does not use any features unavailable in that engine, then a migration might be considered. It's fairly rare for an entire existing SQL-driven application to be moved in its integrality over to NoSQL.

Some NoSQL engines have automatic import-from-SQL features, but using NoSQL imposes some architecture constraints that are dependent on what you are doing with the data, so a hand-written import-from-SQL procedure will usually be the only solution regardless of existing importers.

(Finally, MySQL bears no relationship to NoSQL. MySQL is just a name of one relational database implementation. Since it implements SQL, it is of course not a NoSQL database.)

Answer (score 13):

`NoSQL` vs `SQL` is really about trade-offs.
NoSQL have advantages over traditional SQL databases because they give up certain RDBMS features to gain other performance, scalability and developer usability features.

What NoSQL gives up (varies by NoSQL product):

> - Relationships between entities (like tables). So you usually can't "join" tables or models together in a query.
> - Limited ACID transactions. The level of read consistency and atomic write/commit capabilities across one or more tables/entities varies by NoSQL engine.
> - No standard domain language like SQL for expressing ad-hoc queries. Each NoSQL has its own API and some have of the NoSQL vendors have limited ad-hoc query capability.
> - Less structured and rigid data model. NoSQL typically forces/gives more responsibility at the application layer and to the developer to define the schema - aka "schema on read" instead of on write.

What NoSQL gains:

> - Easier to shard and distribute the data across a cluster (because of what you are giving up above). This can give much higher read/write scalability.
> - Can deploy on cheaper commodity hardware (and in the cloud) and grow sociability more economically.
> - Don't need as much up front DBA type of support. But if your NoSQL gets big you will spend a lot of time doing admin work regardless.
> - NoSQL have a looser data model so you can have sparser data sets and variable data sets organized in documents or name/value column sets. Data models are not as hard wired.
> - Schema migrations can be easier but puts burden on application layer to adjust to changes in data model.
> - Depending on what type of application you are building, NoSQL can make getting started a little easier since you need a less time planning for your data model. So for collecting high velocity and variable data, NoSQL can be great. But for modeling an ERP application it may not be such a great fit.

There is no sliver bullet here with NoSQL There are many different NoSQL engines and each have their own particular specialty and pros and cons. In general you should think of NoSQL as a complementary data storage engine and not as a complete replacement of RDBMS/SQL, but this will depend on your application and functional environment.

Relational databases are also evolving with new hybrid NoSQL like MySQL engines coming out and products like **NuoDB** and **VoltDB** (what some are calling NewSQL) trying to bridge RDBMS into the cloud and the distributed architecture realm.

Answer (score 2):

NoSql is a class of database management system different from traditional relational databases (such as MySql) in that data is not stored using fixed table schemas. Mainly its purpose is to serve as database system for huge web-scale applications (Amazon, Google, Facebook, etc...) where they outperform traditional relational databases.

A good source of info: [NOSQL Databases](http://nosql-database.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, NoSQL database management systems are useful when working with a huge quantity of data when the data's nature does not require a relational model. The data can be structured, but NoSQL is used when what really matters is the ability to store and retrieve great quantities of data, not the relationships between the elements.

Usage examples might be to store millions of key–value pairs in one or a few associative arrays or to store millions of data records. This organization is particularly useful for statistical or real-time analyses of growing lists of elements, such as Twitter posts or the Internet server logs from a large group of users.